# T-sql time logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 columns data like

```
storeID  starttime  endtime
   A       1:00AM    4:00PM
   B       7:30PM    6:00AM
   C       2:00AM    4:00AM
```

I have to check the given time falls between the two time intervals.

Can you suggest a T-SQL statement for that logic?

If suppose if I want to get stores which are open at 1:00AM, I have to get `A, B` as the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @testTime time
select @testTime = '01:00'
select storeId from openinghours 
    where (startTime<=endTime and @testTime >=startTime and @testTime <=endTime) 
        OR (startTime>endTime and (@testTime <startTime OR @testTime > endTime))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @testTime time 
select @testTime = '01:00' 
select storeId from openinghours where @testime between starttime and endtime
```